# How do you pull out common methods that depend on local variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

I'm using Node.js and am creating some models for my different objects.  This is a simplified version of what they look like at the moment.

```
var Foo = module.exports = function () {

    var values = { type: 'foo', prop1: '', prop2: '' };

    function model() {}

    model.init = function(val) {
        _.extend(values, val);
        return model;
    }

    model.store = function(cb) {
        db.insert(values.type, values, cb);
    }

    model.prop1 = function(val) {
        if(!arguments.length) return values.prop1;
        values.prop1 = val;
        return model;
    }

    return model;
}
```

Then I can do:

```
var foo = Foo();
foo.init({prop1: 'a', prop2: 'b'}).store(function(err) { ... });
```

A lot of the functions, like `model.init` and `model.store` are going to be identical for every model, but they depend on local variables in the closure like `values`.

Is there a way to pull these functions into a base class that I can then extend each of models with instead of duplicating all of this code? I would like to end up with something like this, but I'm not sure what the `base` class should look like or the right way to use it to extend `Foo`.

```
var Foo = module.exports = function () {

    var values = { type: 'foo', prop1: '', prop2: '' };

    function model() { this.extend(base); }

    model.prop1 = function(val) {
        if(!arguments.length) return values.prop1;
        values.prop1 = val;
        return model;
    }

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Use properties instead? `this.values = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do something like this;

model.js

```
/** require your db and underscore varialbles etc.. **/

module.exports = function(values, base) {
    var model = typeof base == 'function' ? base : function() {};

    model.init = function(val) {
        _.extend(values, val);
        return model;
    }

    model.store = function(cb) {
       db.insert(values.type, values, cb);
    }

    return model;
}
```

then the usage would be similar to;

```
var Foo = module.exports = function () {

    var values = { type: 'foo', prop1: '', prop2: '' };

    var model = require('/path/to/model.js')(values);

    model.prop1 = function(val) {
        if(!arguments.length) return values.prop1;
        values.prop1 = val;
        return model;
    }

    return model;
}
```

If you need to extend the constructor

```
var Foo = module.exports = function () {

    var values = { type: 'foo', prop1: '', prop2: '' },
        model  = function() { ...something here... };

    require('/path/to/model.js')(values, model);

    model.prop1 = function(val) {
        if(!arguments.length) return values.prop1;
        values.prop1 = val;
        return model;
    }

    return model;
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing it slightly differently, but this got me 90% of the way there.  Thanks!